Sig figures with bearings
Assuming you have the below question, would the number of significant figures be 2 as per the angle or is the angle amount not taken into account and the number of sig figures should be 3?
An asteroid, initially at rest, explodes into three pieces. One part has a momentum of 8530 kg m/s [E] and another has a mass of 2780 kg with velocity 12.9 m/s [W 12° S]. The mass of the third part is 375.00 kg. What is its velocity and kinetic energy?
